# NodeJS { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }

Tags: node.js, request

I use Node **v0.12.18** and Express v4, and for one POST request, I got this error :

```
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:215:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:300:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

With this code :

```
optionsYoutube = {
    host: dostsub_host,
    port: 80,
    path: '/api/media/'+ uuid +'/youtube/push',
    method: 'POST',
    timeout: 1200000, //20 min
    headers: {
        'Authorization': auth
    }
};

console.log('TRY > Youtube');

var postYoutube = http.request(optionsYoutube, function(json) {
    json.on('data', function(d) {
        body += d;
    });                         
    json.on('end', function() { 
    .....

     }).on('error', function(err) {
         console.log(err);
         return next(err);
});
```

I try to use this API : https://dotsub.com/apidoc/api#youtube

I looked that can be a problem of timeout, so I set in my app.js :

```
// set timeout
var timeout = require('connect-timeout');
app.use(timeout(1200000));
app.use(haltOnTimedout);

function haltOnTimedout(req, res, next){
  if (!req.timedout) next();
}
```

But it changed nothing. How can I have more informations on the error ?

Comment: Is the goal here to upload something to YouTube? There may already be a library for this. The reset might come about due to not framing your upload correctly.

Comment: Yes it is the goal, but we use Dotsub for translations too, so we sync translations from Dotsub to Youtube after. I will see with Dotsub so.